React frontend, node backend: Cors policy error
I have recently built a new project which has react on the frontend and a node js server as the backend. The API calls worked on localhost with cors but when I published to vercel i keep running into the same error no matter how much i change my cors settings. If anyone knows how to fix this error:
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://portfolio-5-0-backend.vercel.app/api/send-email' from origin 'https://portfolio-5-0-frontend.vercel.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

cors settings:
const allowedOrigins = ["https://portfolio-5-0-frontend-2c3fpno4h-kroplewskims-projects.vercel.app", "https://portfolio-5-0-frontend.vercel.app"];

const corsOptions = {
  origin: function (origin, callback) {
    if (!origin || allowedOrigins.indexOf(origin) !== -1) {
      callback(null, { origin: true });
    } else {
      callback(new Error("Not allowed by CORS"));
    }
  },
  methods: ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE"],
  allowedHeaders: ["Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Origin", "X-Requested-With", "Content-Type", "Accept", "Authorization"],
  credentials: false,
};

app.options("*", cors(corsOptions));
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.use(bodyParser.json());


react api call:
  const onSubmit = handleSubmit(async (data) => {
    try {
      PushNotification("Sending email...", "bg-info");
      const response = await axios.post("https://portfolio-5-0-backend.vercel.app/api/send-email", {
        Email: data.Email,
        Name: data.Name,
        Message: data.Message,
      }, {
        withCredentials: true,
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
      });
      if (response.status === 200) {
        PushNotification("Email sent successfully!...", "bg-success");
      }
    } catch (e) {
      PushNotification("Failed to send email", "bg-error");
      console.log(e);
    }
  });

The url that im trying to make the API call from is: https://portfolio-5-0-frontend.vercel.app/

I have added the OPTIONS method and still the same issue

@esqew Contrary to popular belief, OPTIONS only needs to be listed as an allowed method in the CORS config if the server wishes to allow actual OPTIONS requests from clients. It's never required for preflight requests.

@Mat app.options("*", cors(corsOptions)); should not be necessary. Also, you can safely drop "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" and "Origin" from the list of allowed request headers in your CORS configuration. Finally, if the client sends credentialed requests (withCredentials: true), then the server's CORS configuration needs to allow credentials (credentials: true).

try this:
app.use(cors( {
credentials: true,
preflightContinue: true,
methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH' , 'DELETE', 'OPTIONS'],
origin: ['*','http://localhost','your_domain'] } ));


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
